# onClick event propagation in overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have two absolutely positioned `div`s which overlap, each with an `onClick` handler. I need the `onClick` handler to fire for each element, but it's only occurring for whichever is on top. I'm using React 17.

Example code:

```
<div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 200, 200, 0.2)",
    }}
    onClick={() => console.log("first")}
  />
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(200, 200, 0, 0.2)",
    }}
    onClick={() => console.log("second")}
  />
</div>
```

Render:

[image: render]

Clicking on either non-overlapped portion logs `'first'` or `'second'` to the console, but clicking the overlapped section only logs `'second'`.

How can the event be propagated to the element behind as well?

(This is almost certainly a duplicate, but after a ton of searching I haven't found any similar questions.)

Comment: you want the onclick to be working on the overlapped portion or the whole part?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal i want both handlers to fire on the overlapped portion only

Comment: how can that be possible considering our browsers canvas is 2 dimensional?

Comment: sorry, but i do not understand the question: the browser knows that both of those elements are being rendered under the coordinates that are being clicked. that's how it knows to blend the background colors.

Comment: okay so tell me one thing. which element do you want to be triggered when someone clicks on the overlapped place? because technically both of them are there. Do you want them both to be triggered?

Comment: yes, I want them both to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out that solved the problem I had, though it did not technically achieve the stated question. I really only needed a single element to receive the event, but that was sometimes the one behind.

I bumped the `z-index;` of the intended target to a high value so that it would sit on top and receive the click. This only happened to be a problem because I'm using transparent elements.